# state-of-the-art C++ projects

Tags: c++

I like to go through existing software projects as a source of learning and new ideas.
doing so I discover things that I did not think were possible

in your opinion, what is the top state of the art C++ project that you have used/develop/extended?  can you state reasons why you consider it state of the art and what you can learn from it.

my latest craze is boost::phoenix, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html, which is very comprehensive functional programming library.
Despite its capabilities it is straightforward and easy to extend.  After some tweaking I was able to write multithreaded lambda parallel loops and mathematical domain specific language, probably within 2 weeks.

What is yours?  (please do not just say boost, as it is huge collection of project)

Comment: Is the question limited to open-source projects?

Comment: @Simon well, if you think you can get idea from documentation of close source project, I have no problem with that.  Still be nice to read actual implementation

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109684/what-are-some-examples-of-exceptional-c-open-source-code

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I like to look at code in [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).  I do use it everyday, but it seems like every day I use it, I find something new.  In terms of total code, it is probably as big as boost.  But it comes with excellent documentation and examples and complete source code and is free for LPGL & GPL versions.

For me, what I liked about Qt was that it's concepts matched the way C# works, so it was a fairly easy transition back into c++ for me.  But  by looking at their code, it has really given me many ways (although not as many as SO) to understand some of the complexity in C++

Comment: "Personally, I like to look at code in Qt." I second that. Qt 4 helped me a lot to develop my own coding style.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, the code-sources that I have learned the most from have been from fairly complex 3rd party software libraries. Havok is an excellent example from which I've not only learned programming practices and solutions, but also quite a few mathematical and philosophical discussions. I've also seen some other code-sources which have not been open sourced from which I've learned how to not solve things.

Game engines for AAA-titles in general tend to involve a lot of complex code that tries to push as much as possible through a piece of hardware. I guess that the recommendation goes for all software that tries to achieve something similar but I've only dived into game engines when it comes to such software. AAA-titled game engines often have good or bad solutions to study and I would generally recommend looking into those. There are some that are open source... I think Source/Valve have released theirs in different stages.